# Callback function to $apply() in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

What I want to do is push an object to an array which have angularjs binding to html, then do a click function on the new created element.
the code is like this

```
$scope.fruits = {"orange", "plum", "cherry"};
$scope.add = function() {
    $scope.fruits.push("apple");
    //this would add an element to the html, then I want to click on the element
    $('#fruits').children.eq(-1).click();//click the last element (which has just been created)
}
```

the html is like:

```
<div id="fruits">
    <div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is, when an object is pushed to the model, angular would do something like $scope.$apply() to dynamically update the html.
If I click the last element with .children().eq(-1).click(), it won't wait after the new element been created, what it actually clicks is the "cherry" div.

I tried to call $scope.$apply() before click(), it works, but I got this error message:

```
$apply already in progress
```

which I believe is not a good practise, and $apply() should not be called in this way.

Comment: Could you explain more about what your click action is doing?  I think it would be better to look for an alternative way of achieving your end goal, without using click().

Comment: Right. I have an accordion (bootstrap) and a button to add a new panel to the accordion. What I want to do is expand the new panel and close others when you click the "create" button.

Comment: This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but here's an example that will expand the last panel in an accordian when they are re-rendered (like when you add a new panel to the end).   http://plnkr.co/edit/fSevqkgzQ9WB7fqerdja?p=info  If you have additional info of your requirements (like what panel will be initially expanded, will new panels always be appended to the end) then maybe I could help with a more specific solution.

Comment: Thanks @CraigSquire, you inspire me to set the is-open attribute to check if it is the last one: is-open="$last". This would do even better that expand the last one when created while closing others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add to the $scope you are inside a digest loop and the DOM won't be compiled and refreshed until those loops complete - basically in your $scope push you are changing the array but at that moment the rendered DOM still has the previous items. Once it exits the loop, the watchers from the repeater will fire and render the new DOM element, but you've already left your controller.

The solution is really simple. You just need to queue your update for the moment the current digest loop ends. You can do that using setTimeout with no delay. this will put your function on the queue and call it when the current processing is done:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('#fruits').children().eq(-1).click();
}, 0);
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/bWeQL/

(I strongly encourage you to consider writing a directive for this to avoid manipulating the DOM directly from within your controller).

Comment: Well this solves and helps me know more about angular apply/digest loop. I am not sure how to write a directive to manipulate the is-open variable as the accordion directive is written by angular-ui. Thanks

Comment: I'd use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` to stay in the angular world when the timer callback is called. Here you are just triggering a click using jQuery but in real life you might update the scope and doing so outside the angular world will cause UI update issues.